# Fast conversion of c char numpy array to list of python strings

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numpy-ndarray

I'm making an interface between Python and Fortran code with Cython. One part of that is retrieving arrays of strings. In Fortran,

```
character(len=3) :: str_array(:)
```

For the sake of this example, suppose `str_array` contains the following

```
allocate(str_array(2))
str_array = ['abc','def']
```

My approach is to return this to Cython as a single C char array. I end up with a numpy array of byte strings:

```py
c_str_arr = np.array([b'a', b'b', b'c', b'd', b'e', b'f'], dtype='|S1')
```

I then convert this numpy array to a list of python strings with the following python code:

```py
str_len = 3
arr_len = 2
c_str_arr.shape = (arr_len,str_len)
str_arr = []
for i in range(arr_len):
    str_arr.append(b''.join(c_str_arr[i]).decode())
```

But this is pretty slow.

**My question:** Is there a faster way to convert `c_str_arr` to a list of python strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, avoid iteration over the array. This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but try:

```
bs = c_str_arr.tobytes()
str_arr = [bs[i:i+str_len].decode() for i in range(0, str_len*arr_len, str_len)]
```

Comment: Much faster! Thanks! My method was taking 8 ms for one test case. Your method takes 300 us.